# Crystal field hamiltonian using Stevens operators

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, hamiltonian, crystals

I am trying to explicitly find (or understand how to find at first) Hamilton operators for crystal fields in different symmetries, e.g. $T_d$, using Stevens operators. The Hamiltonian is then of the form
$H_{CEF} = \sum_{l,m} B_l^m O^m_l$
with the CEF parameters $B_l^m$ and the Stevens operators $O^m_l$. I managed to find some specific examples (for example in a cubic symmetry given in Bauer and Rotter,
`Magnetism of Complex Metallic Alloys: Crystalline Electric Field effects`, Eq. 48, or tables showing which terms vanish) but I have no idea how to generallyfind the non-zero terms of this sum and their prefactors.

Are there any text books explaining this? Or does anyone here know the strategy for solving this?